# How to have 2 condition to an if in jquery

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I would like my if to activate only when the two conditions are validated. I tried this but can't figure out how to do it...

```
if (document.getElementById('SSD-250G'&&'HDD-1T').checked){
    $('#ssd-check').css({'background-color':'green'})
}
```

Comment: You have to put multiple conditions in that `case`

Answer (score 4):

You'll have to do it twice if you want pure JS :

```
if (document.getElementById('SSD-250G').checked && document.getElementById('HDD-1T').checked){
    $('#ssd-check').css({'background-color':'green'})
}
```

```js
if (document.getElementById('SSD-250G').checked && document.getElementById('HDD-1T').checked){
    $('#ssd-check').css({'background-color':'green'})
}
```

```css
#ssd-check {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="SSD-250G" checked />
<input type="checkbox" id="HDD-1T" checked />
<div id="ssd-check">
</div>
```

Or, using jQuery :

```
if ($('#SSD-250G').is(':checked') && $('#HDD-1T').is(':checked')){
    $('#ssd-check').css({'background-color':'green'})
}
```

```js
if ($('#SSD-250G').is(':checked') && $('#HDD-1T').is(':checked')){
    $('#ssd-check').css({'background-color':'green'})
}
```

```css
#ssd-check {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="SSD-250G" checked />
<input type="checkbox" id="HDD-1T" checked />
<div id="ssd-check">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jQuery you can do as follow:

```
if(jQuery('#SSD-250G').prop('checked') && jQuery('#HDD-1T').prop('checked')){
 jQuery('#ssd-check').css({'background-color':'green'})
}
```